# Oracle client in Windows 7: how to change looking path for sqlnet.ora

Tags: oracle, client

For some security reasons I'm not able to amend the file `sqlnet.ora`, must meet security policies applied. Is it possible to change the search path of this file to some other drive/folder?

Thank you!

Comment: Set the environment variable `TNS_ADMIN` to the directory where your custom `sqlnet.ora` is found.

Comment: What exactly do you need to accomplish? Please provide more information... Because in my understanding, you have the sqlfile.ora in folder A for example and are trying to change TNS_ADMIN to search it on folder B. So in this case, how will sqlnet.ora policies will be enforced? Or are these security policies outside the realm of Oracle? Are you on linux? Setting TNS_ADMIN variable + Symbolic Links can be considered.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to set the environment variable `TNS_ADMIN` to the directory in which you have your `sqlnet.ora` file?